# Homework-Subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector

Tags: c

I am copying a program whose purpose is to generate and bubble sort a list of random numbers. This is the code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    #define MAX 10

    int a;
    int rand_seed=10;

    int rand()
    {
        rand_seed = rand_seed * 1103515245 + 12345;
        return (unsigned int)(rand_seed / 65536) % 32768;
    }

    void main()
    {
    int i,t,x,y;

//fill array
for (i = 0; i < MAX;i++)
    {
        a = rand();
        printf("%d\n",a);
    }
 /* bubble sort the array */


    for (x = 0; x < MAX-1; x++)
        for (y = 0; y < MAX -x - 1; y++)
            if (a > a[y+1]) {
            t = a;
            a = a[y+1];
            a[y+1] = t;
            }


printf("----------------\n");
for( i = 0; i < MAX;i++)
    printf("%d\n",a);
    }
```

I know it's offensive to post the whole thing here but I don't know where the problem is.

Comment: How do you know there's a problem? If it was a compiler error it should have told you exactly where the problem is. If it is producing incorrect results then important info like that should be included in your question.

Comment: the a variable must be defined as array, not as int: int a[MAX];

Answer (score 0):

I believe your compiler already had the offensive line pointed out. In the code

```
if (a > a[y+1])
```

you're trying to use `a` as an *array*, while it was defined as an `int`, earlier

```
int a;
```

If you want `a` to be an array, you have to define it as an array, and populate *each* member using `rand()` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure you wanted `a` to be an array. In that case try this out:

```
int a[10];

for (i = 0; i < MAX;i++) {
    a[i] = rand();
    printf("%d\n",a[i]);
}
```

And also this part would be changed into:

```
if (a[y] > a[y+1]) {
    t = a[y];
    a[y] = a[y+1];
    a[y+1] = t;
}
```